# retrieve a complex JSON response and display the parts that I want from it

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

this is the first time I use JSON and underscore.js.

I'm getting a JSON response  :

> response           Object { numFound=12, start=0, docs=[10]}
>   responseHeader       Object { status=0, QTime=1, params={...}}

the docs nested array has another nested array like this

0 { id="23", name="8asjkdnsd",absolute_path="kkskskmasd8234", more... }
.
.
.
9 { id="89234", name="awdcs",absolute_path="qwdacsc", more... }

I want to use underscore.js in my jquery script to convert the response to an array to be able to access any key, value pair when I want to, like if I want to print all the names inside the docs[10]?

I'm trying something like this :

> _.each(response.docs.name, function(docs){console.log(response.name);});

but I'm getting undefined and actually I don't know what I'm doing. so any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About this line of code... you can read the reference of underscore [each](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

```
_.each(response.docs.name, function(docs){console.log(response.name);});
```

The first argument of each needs to be an array and I don't think this is the case of response.docs.name, which probably is a String.

Comment: Thanks you're right, I just solved it and I had to do something like: result.response.docs which is the array I want